# Terminal - Right Click Menu Size

Tags: 17.10, gnome-terminal

I have a weird problem with Terminal on my Ubuntu 17.10.

Whenever I expand Terminal program to full screen, right menu size shrinks, making it unusable. However this problem does not exists when I run terminal at default size or change size of the terminal window size gradually from sides while left button is pressed.

This is default window size & normal behavior:
[image]

This one is the full screen Terminal with shrunk right menu size:
[image]

Any kind of support will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, any news on this?

Comment: It seems to be a bug, but I have not being able to find a solution. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1731888

Answer (score 0):

The search for a solution to the problem led nowhere.
For myself as a solution to this problem, I chose another terminal emulator: Tilix
To install Tilix:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/terminix
apt-get install tilix
```

To work with hotkey term in unity, you need to run command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'tilix'
```